# UnicodeEncodeError occurs when attempting to migrate MSSQL data to MariaDB with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, encoding, mariadb, migration, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to move data from SQL Server to MariaDB using MySQL Workbench.

I installed it as 8.0.27 version at first, and after the problem occurred, I downgraded it to 8.0.26 version, but the problem was not solved.

I'm confused whether it's a problem with the data you're trying to move or something that's happening in MySQL Workbench.

I tried googling, but there was a similar phenomenon, but I couldn't find an answer.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105772

Can you give me some advice?
thanks you.

> ------------------------------------------------------------------ Starting... Create Script File...
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0
> CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 71, in run
> self.func()   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\migration_schema_creation.py", line 188, in
> _create_script_task
> self.main.plan.createTargetScript(self.main.plan.state.objectCreationParams["CreateSQLFile"])
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0
> CE\modules\migration.py", line 527, in createTargetScript
> grt.modules.DbMySQLFE.createScriptForCatalogObjects(path, self.migrationTarget.catalog, self.state.objectCreationParams)
> SystemError: UnicodeEncodeError("'charmap' codec can't encode
> characters in position 99-104: character maps to "): error
> calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.createScriptForCatalogObjects
> ERROR: Error during Create Script File: UnicodeEncodeError("'charmap'
> codec can't encode characters in position 99-104: character maps to
> "): error calling Python module function
> DbMySQLFE.createScriptForCatalogObjects ERROR: Exception in task
> 'Create Script File': SystemError('UnicodeEncodeError("'charmap'
> codec can't encode characters in position 99-104: character maps to
> "): error calling Python module function
> DbMySQLFE.createScriptForCatalogObjects')
>
> ### Failed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qhXm.png)

Comment: Please find the hex for the character(s) that it is complaining about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are seeing `\uFFFD`, that is the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER - - �

It means that the data was *already* corrupted beyond repair.  Go back a step in the process of the data to see what *first* led to it.

See also "black diamond" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) to find some ways that it can occur purely in MySQL.  However, it sounds like SQL Server created it; I think the problem is back there.

Fetch the hex for any characters involved, noting that `\uFFDD` (UTF-8 hex: `EFBFBD`) is after things are already corrupted.

In UTF-8 (MySQL's utf8 or utf8mb4), Hex EAB0zz through ED9Ezz is used for Hangul (Korean).  For example, `박상우` is hex `EBB095 EC8381 EC9AB0` (minus the spaces).